# How to use Bash script or awk to extract a file name

Tags: bash, awk

I receive files with names constructed in the following format

```
[2letters e.g.AF][6-digit-number sequence][Date in ccyymmdd][Time in hhmmss]
```

For Example:

```
AF00010720120917144500.csv
```

I want to automate loading such files onto my database using the date part of the file.

something which may start like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename_datepart=$(echo `date -d "1 day ago" +"%d%m%Y"`)
filename="/home/hlosi/AF000107"$filename_datepart".csv"
```

But remember, the part `000107` changes with each new file.

Comment: How many files do you expect per day?  Also, wouldn't you need the Time in `hhmmsss`?

Comment: I receive one file per day. I have tried reasoning with the data source about  excluding the time part since it's only one file a day to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a BASH solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

#The full name
fullname="/home/hlosi/AF00010720120917144500.csv"

#Rip off the directory
file=$(basename "$fullname")

#Now pull out just the characters that we want
extract=$(echo "$file" | cut -c3-8)
echo "You want: $extract"
```

Comment: Thanks, I have adapted this one to part of my problem. I will try it and get back to you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Bash has built-ins so you don't need `cut` either, but you have to do it in stages; `cuttail=${file#????????}; cutc8=${file%$cuttail}; echo "${cutc8#??}"`. Note also the use of double quotes when you interpolate a variable, except in assignments.

Comment: @tripleee -- I learned shell scripting before `bash` was common -- I tend to stick the old ways.  You are right about the quotes though, I should have put those in.

Comment: Actually the string substitutions go pretty far back; they are certainly not Bash-only.

Comment: Since the date part is at a fixed location, `${file:8:8}` is one-step solution in `bash` (although not POSIX).

Answer (score 1):

You can use wildcards to fill in the unknown values

```
#!/bin/bash
file=/home/hlosi/AF??????`date -d "1 day ago" +"%d%m%Y"`??????.csv
echo $file
```

Comment: This worked fine: `file=/home/hlosi/AF*`date -d "1 day ago" +"%d%m%Y"`*.csv`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this. In case you have to handle multiple files.

```
#!/bin/bash
fpath=/home/hlosi/
filename_datepart=$(echo `date -d "1 day ago" +"%d%m%Y"`)
files=$(find $fpath -iname "*$filename_datepart.csv")
for file in $files
do
    echo "found file: " $file
done
```

Comment: Especially since these people take days to remove old files, my script may have to choose the correct file using the date part.

Answer (score 0):

forgive me for my ignorance there is -atime -ctime -mtime I think its -ctime

```
find  -ctime 1  -name \*.csv -print
```

-mtime  match ending of csv and are exactly 1 day old, the trouble of this is it works in 24 hour period so files less than 24 hours but still yesterday would not show

this would be a simpler way of doing things since and would not care about changes in file name formatting for future proofing.

```
cd pathtcsv;
d=`date -d "1 day ago" +"%d"`
d=$d find . -type f -name \*.csv -ctime 1 -exec ls -l {} \;|awk '$7 ~ d'|awk '{print $NF}'|  awk '{ print substr( $0, length($0) - 1, length($0) ) }'
```

# D = $d which is set as yesterday's date, it finds files from yseterday that have csv ending it then does an ls, pipes into awk and checks out value 7 against the date of yesterday which $7 is the date value on ls -l, it finally prints the last field and pipes into a final awk which prints the string and splits from char position to char position which is what you wanted ? you need to figure out what chars you need here is another example of above for char positions of 0 to 10.

```
 d=$d find . -type f  -ctime 1 -name \*.csv -exec ls -l {} \;|awk '$7 ~ d'|awk '{print $NF}'|  awk '{ print substr( $0, 0, 10)}'
```